# Phonegap connection issue

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

I currently have a production phonegap app (3.3.0) installed on an iPad. It's sends an ajax request to sync data to a server. No updates have been made to the app or server but for some reason it's stopped connecting to the server. The iPad can connect through safari with no issues.

I've read information regarding a whitelist on the app though I never had this in place and we never had an issue. Other iPads with the same version of the application are connecting with no issues.

My initial thoughts were a update was made to the iPad which blocked access, though there are no restrictions in place. Anyone seen this type of issue or any thoughts on what the issue could be?

There is data with the local DB we need to retrieve so I don't want to re-install the app as I'll lose the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,